# How to select faces by area

Tags: faces, selection-tools

I found this documentation: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html

Under "Face Selection Mode" it says:

> #### Face Selection Mode:
>
> ...
>
> **Area**
>   Selects all faces that have a similar area as those already selected.

But I can't figure out where in blender this option is hiding?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is listed under [Select Similar](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/dev/modeling/meshes/selecting/advanced.html#select-similar) which has a <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> shortcut and can be found in the Select menu.

Note that the area option (and others face/edge related) is only available if face select mode is the only active selection mode, if you have multiple selection modes active you will not see the option.

[image: select similar menu]