# Selecting polygons by size

Tags: selection-tools

Is there a way to select all the polygons within a mesh having a size similar to a given one.

The idea was to have an automatic selection of all the polygons within a range of size similar to one you select.

I think it could be done by scripting something using polygon.select and polygon.area, but I have no idea how to start.

I am not a coder but if someone gave me good indications and it is not going to be particularly difficult I could try to make a script.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79324/how-to-select-faces-by-area. You can use Select SImilar > Area or Perimer depending on the scenario.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use the following menu:

[image]

Select your required polygon, go to **Select -> Select similar -> Area**

Best of luck!

Answer (score 3):

In Edit mode, press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> and click *Faces*. Select the face you want and press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> (*Select similar* menu) and click *Area* in the menu :

[image: Select similar menu]

In the opertor property panel (press <kbd>T</kbd> to make the *Tool shelf* visible), increase or decrease the *Threashold* :

[image: operator property panel]